# Symfony 3 routing subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, subdomain

I have to bundles, frontend and backend. I want the subdomain "admin.domain.com" to work as "admin.domain.com/whateverpage" and controlled by the backend bundle controllers. All other subdomains should work like "sub1.domain.com/{dynamicwhateverpage}" or "sub2.domain.com/{dynamicwhateverpage}" and be controlled by the frontend bundle controllers.

I got it to work with "admin.domain.com/backend/whateverpage" and "sub1.domain.com/frontend/{dynamicwhateverpage}". The backend and frontend in the URL of course should not be visible to the users. Is there a way to rewrite with htaccess? Or is there even a better way to achieve this kind of rewriting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony can [match routing based on host](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/hostname_pattern.html). This should also work when [importing routes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/external_resources.html), though I have not tested it;

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="project_page", host="{project}.example.com")
 */
public function projectPageAction($project) {
    // ...
}
```

Just make sure your none dynamic routes are loaded before the all capturing one, or make sure the project one can't match eg. admin.

> #### Earlier Routes Always Win
>
> Why would you ever care about requirements? If a request matches two routes, then the first route always wins.

Comment: Thank you for your answer **Earlier Routes Always Win**. Sometimes it needs just a hint when not seeing the forest because of lots of trees ;)

The ordering in my routing.yml was wrong with the imported routes.